# C# Allow user to enter conditional rules

Tags: c#, user-interface, business-logic, conditional-operator, conditional-statements

I write code in isolation, that is I work for myself. I need some advice on how you might implement the following functionality or if there are some tools that already exist to help make this task easier to accomplish.

I have a scenario (C# application) in which I would like the user to be able to enter conditional rules which will then be used elsewhere in the program for various calculations.

As a simple example let's say we have a TimeRequiredForJob property and we need to calculate this in the program based upon the users rules. A simple rule might be

TimeRequiredForJob = 200 Balloons multiplied by 5 min each, or
TimeRequiredForJob = 20% of HoursInAfternoon

I am guessing its pretty hard to see what I am looking for so maybe the following image will help:
[image: DevExpress XtraGrid Filter Example]

This is from DevExpress XtraGrid and it allows a user to filter data displayed in the grid based upon the users custom filter rules. I would like to implement something similar but be able to save the rules to a database and use those rules later in the application.

Any suggestions or tips welcome.

[Late Edit]

Actually I am getting some good information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644146/user-defined-formulas-in-c) but any additional information will be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for posting the picture Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgetting about the GUI for a second, you will need to first need to build some kind of rule evaluation processor.

You may find this article on building an [Evaluation Engine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/EvaluationEngine.aspx) helpful. It describes processing text expressions into a form that can be evaluated.

Once you have a way of representing these rules (either as an object structure or as text expressions) the task of building a GUI to suit your specific requirements will become easier.

Comment: Wow, great article and looks like some good (required) reading. I'll make myself a cup of coffee and have a look now. Thanks!

Comment: Simon, thanks again. The Expression Engine you pointed me to should work for my application. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Macondo: No problem, glad it helped, although if you want to thank the author there is a comments box at the bottom of the article.